# Creating a view on a non-existing view

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a whole bunch of views that I need to create. Many of these views depend on other views.

If I create a view that depends on a view not yet created, I get an *Invalid Object* error.

Rather than go through the whole lot and work out the dependencies and then deal with creating them all in the correct order, is there a way I can just switch this checking off until all the views are created?

It is possible to delete a dependant view after the view is installed, so it is possible for the database to be in a state where a view exists that depends on a non-existent object. I need it to accept being in this state during creation..

Comment: Oracle has `CREATE FORCE VIEW` for exactly this use case, but I don't believe SQL Server has any equivalent.

Comment: @Gaius - it seems SQL Server only has an equivalent for Stored Procedures, not Views.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to adatabase that the views exist within you can query sys.views to determine the order in which they where created. Query below should help with this, add a predicate to filter the list if it helps.

```
SELECT v.name   
FROM sys.views v
ORDER BY v.create_date
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for the pathologically lazy - instead of CREATE use CREATE OR ALTER. Run the view scripts repeatedly until there are no *Invalid Object* errors.

In each iteration views without dependencies, and those whose dependencies were satisfied in the previous iteration, will succeed. The OR ALTER bit accommodates those object which were created in a previous round. Thus more object exist after each round until all are in place.

SQL Server 2016+.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge it's not possible to create a view that is missing objects referenced in that view.

Why is it such a pain to know what the dependencies are on your views?  You are **CREATING** them, right?

Do they already exist in another database?  If so you can use SSMS or SMO to script them out in dependency order and bypass this issue.

Comment: Darn it.. Yeah its just sheer laziness / efficiency (depending on how you look at it).

Comment: [tsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsort_(Unix)) is your friend.